# Twitter Search API not iterating

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, iterator

Twitter streaming API returns a valid JSON data and is iterable.
While, When the same I applied on Twitter Search API, it does not iterate.

This is code for streaming api and works completely fine:

```
try:
    import json

except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream


#Authentication keys from apps.twitter.com
ACCESS_TOKEN = '******'
ACEESS_SECRET = '******'
CONSUMER_KEY = '******'
CONSUMER_SECRET =  '******'

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACEESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

#Initiate the connection to Twitter Streaming API
twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=oauth)

# Get a sample of the public data following through Twitter
# iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()


#Filter tweets containing term Google
iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track = 'Google', language = 'en')

#Limiting number of tweets, not mandatory
tweet_count = 100
for tweet in iterator:
    tweet_count -=1


    print json.dumps(tweet, indent = 4)

    if tweet_count <= 0:
        break
```

This code is for Search API does not iterate. BUT when i directly print iterator, it gives data (not well formatted JSON)

```
try:
    import json

except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream

trend = '#india'
#Authentication keys from apps.twitter.com
ACCESS_TOKEN = '******'
ACEESS_SECRET = '******'
CONSUMER_KEY = '******'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '******'

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACEESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

# Initiate the connection to Twitter REST API
twitter = Twitter(auth=oauth)

for tweet in iterator:

    print json.dumps(tweet, indent = 4)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why is it not iterating or returning a proper JSON ?